# How to provide multiple dependencies in --chunk for closure compiler?

Tags: google-closure-compiler, google-closure, google-closure-library, google-closure-templates

I have this requirement where i have test.js file dependent on x and y modules. So i was trying something like,

The below code generates x and y successfully but breaks on producing the test module.

How can i pass multiple dependencies? If we can't do this via chunk then how else can we do this?

```
OPTS = (
"--js app1.js"
"--chunk app:1" 
"--js x1.js"
"--chunk x:1:app" 
"--js y1.js"
"--chunk y:1:app"
"--js test1.js"
"--chunk test:3:[x,y]"
)

java -jar comipler.jar $(echo ${OPTS[*]}).
```

Thanks in advance for the help,

Kiran

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with this too -- it's a comma-separated list in quotes.

Using your example:

```
--chunk test:3:"x,y"
```

Can confirm this works in Powershell and bash.

[Documentation on the --chunk flag](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/Flags-and-Options#code-splitting)